# jQuery toggle help

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, clicking on the h2 tag toggles the div with slideToggle. However, I'm trying to also fade in and out the `.hint_text_heading` that exists within the h2 tag. So, originally, what I tried to do at least, I am adding an `.active`  class to the h2 tag thats open, then fading in the `.hint_text_heading`. However, I can't get `.hint_text_heading` to fade out when I close the div.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

## html

```
<h2 class="collapsible_head">This is a title.<span class="hint_text_heading">This is a hint.</span></h2>
<div>
  This is the toggled content.
</div>
```

## jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.hint_text_heading').hide();
    $('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('h2.active span.hint_text_heading').fadeIn();
    }).next().hide();
});
```

UPDATE/

Here's an example in jsFiddle. As you can see, the div toggles, and the hint text fades in, however, when the div is hidden, the hint text remains. I am trying to get that to fade out:

http://jsfiddle.net/UGHgx/

Comment: What do you mean, "When you close the div"?

Comment: But what is the event that closes the div? A second click?

Comment: Yes. @Kokos and @NeXXeuS answered correctly below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you are wanting:

**CSS:**

```
span.hint_text_heading { display: none; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    //$(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('span.hint_text_heading', this).fadeToggle();
}).next().hide();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, your code also helps me to gain some knowledge about `fadeToggle()`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
$(function(){ /* shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){ */

    $('span.hint_text_heading').hide();
    $('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {

        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('h2.active span.hint_text_heading').fadeIn();
        $('h2:not(.active) span.hint_text_heading').fadeOut();

    }).next().hide();

});
```

**Edit:**
I would also recommend removing `$('span.hint_text_heading').hide();` and just putting `display:none;` as a style, this is extra javascript where it isn't needed.

Comment: when there's jQuery, there's always a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.hint_text_heading').hide();
    $('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {
        $(this).children('.hint_text_heading').fadeOut().end().next().slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('h2.active span.hint_text_heading').fadeIn();
    }).next().hide();
});
```

If not, please comment me and I'll try to give you solution.

Comment: Yes, this works also, but NeXXeus answer is consolidated even more :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the quick and dirty solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/CpVSC/12/

```
$('span.hint_text_heading').hide();
$('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {

    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
          $('.hint_text_heading').fadeOut(); 
       }else{  
    $('span.hint_text_heading',this).fadeIn();
}
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
}).next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code (tested):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h2.collapsible_head').click(function() {
        $('h2.active span.hint_text_heading').hide();
        $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('h2.active span.hint_text_heading').fadeIn();
    }).children().hide().end().next().hide();
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/UGHgx/3/

Answer (score 0):

I will go with animation callbacks.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X99Z6/